# Typing: Raw value or Container

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'd like to create a parametrized type `RawOrVariable[T] = Union[T, Variable[T]]` so that

```py
def foo(a: RawOrVariable[str]):
    ...
def bar(b: RawOrVariable[int]):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```py
def foo(a: Union[str, Variable[str]]):
    ...
def bar(b: Union[int, Variable[int]]):
    ...
```

Is there a shortcut or do I need to write a class `RawOrVariable` myself? E.g. like so:

```py
@type_check_only
class RawOrVariable:
   def __class_getitem__(cls, t):
       return Union[t, Variable[t]]
```

What do I have to be aware of?

### Update

When I use the above `RawOrVarialbe`, mypy complains: `"RawOrVariable" expects no type arguments, but 1 given`. What do I have to do differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create my own "parameterized" type in Python (like \`Optional\[T\]\`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382170/how-can-i-create-my-own-parameterized-type-in-python-like-optionalt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close -- you need to do `RawOrVariable = Union[T, Variable[T]]` instead of `RawOrVariable[T] = Union[T, Variable[T]]`.

Note that the latter isn't valid Python code -- the `RawOrVariable` variable isn't defined at runtime.

For more details, see the [mypy docs on generic type aliases](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-type-aliases). PEP 484 also briefly gives an example of what a generic type alias looks like in the second example [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just discovered independently that my question is a duplicate of an already existing question (that you answered as well)...