# Parameterize a custom type definition Python Typing

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to knok if is possible to parameterize the type in a custom User defined types.

My working example is:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Dict, Union, Optional

ListSchemaType = TypeVar("ListSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
GenericPagination = Dict[str, Union[Optional[int], List[ListSchemaType]]]
```

What i need to do is call GenericPagination with a parameter.

Like this:

```
pagination: GenericPagination(schemas.Posts)
```

My data is structured in this form:

```
    "count": 2,
    "limit": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "results": [{
            "name": "Foo",
            "url_base": "https://www.bar.cl",
            "development_stage": "FOO",
            "system_status": "BAR",
            "id": 1

    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found then answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382170/how-can-i-create-my-own-parameterized-type-in-python-like-optionalt).

My final working case looks:

```
ListSchema = TypeVar("ListSchema", bound=BaseModel)
Pagination = Dict[str, Union[Optional[int], List[ListSchema]]]
```

Then i can just use it like this:

```
pagination: Optional[Pagination[schemas.Post]]
```