# How to make a custom parametrizable type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Say I want to make a type that specifies that an object is a factory, that is, that the object is a `Callable` that returns a specific type. I would do it like so:

```py
from typing import Callable, NewType

ListFactory = NewType('ListFactory', Callable[..., list])
DictFactory = NewType('DictFactory', Callable[..., dict])
```

But what I'd rather do is have a `Factory` type that is "parametrizable", so I could just use `Factory[list]` and `Factory[dict]` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create my own "parameterized" type in Python (like \`Optional\[T\]\`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382170/how-can-i-create-my-own-parameterized-type-in-python-like-optionalt)

Comment: Yes and no. Let's say it wasn't immediately obvious, but it lead me to the actual answer which is: `from typing import Callable, T; Factory = Callable[..., T]`. Do you want to submit this as the answer to my question yourself @mkrieger1?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```py
from typing import T, Callable
Factory = Callable[..., T]
```

and now you have what you want:

```py
>>> Factory[int]
typing.Callable[..., int]
>>> Factory[dict]
typing.Callable[..., dict]
```

The `...` indicate that know assumptions are being made on the inputs of the callable.

*Note: @mkrieger1 pointed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382170/how-can-i-create-my-own-parameterized-type-in-python-like-optionalt), which didn't answer my exact question, but lead me to the answer I was looking for.*