# Python: Type hinting a dictionary mapping types to functions

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to create a dictionary mapping a tuple of input data types to a function to handle those data types. I haven't been able to figure out a way to type-hint it in a way that satisfies mypy. Before I disable static type checking on the file, I figured I'd ask...

Here's a MWE:

```
from typing import Callable

class BaseType: pass
class IntType(BaseType): pass
class StringType(BaseType): pass

def _compare_int_int(before: IntType, after: IntType) -> int:
    return 1

def _compare_int_str(before: IntType, after: StringType) -> int:
    return 2

def _compare_str_int(before: StringType, after: IntType) -> int:
    return 3

def _compare_str_str(before: StringType, after: StringType) -> int:
    return 4


_COMPARERS: dict[tuple[type[BaseType], type[BaseType]], Callable[[BaseType, BaseType], int]] = {
    (IntType, IntType): _compare_int_int,
    (IntType, StringType): _compare_int_str,
    (StringType, StringType): _compare_str_str,
    (StringType, IntType): _compare_str_int
}

def compare(before: BaseType, after: BaseType) -> int:
    compare_func = _COMPARERS[(type(before), type(after))]
    return compare_func(before, after)

a = IntType()
b = StringType()

print(compare(a, a))
## 1
print(compare(a, b))
## 2
print(compare(b, a))
## 3
print(compare(b, b))
## 4
```

It works as desired, but `mypy` gives errors

```
Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Tuple[Type[IntType], Type[IntType]]": "Callable[[IntType, IntType], int]"; expected "Tuple[Type[BaseType], Type[BaseType]]": "Callable[[BaseType, BaseType], int]"
```

and likewise for the other entries.

Any tips for type-hinting this correctly?

I've

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I've also tried using `TypeVar` like so:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseType)
U = TypeVar('U', bound=BaseType)

_COMPARERS: dict[tuple[type[T], type[U]], Callable[[T, U], int]] = {...}
```

Although I liked this idea better (it clarifies that the parameter types of the functions match the respective types of the tuples), it still gives errors:

```
Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Tuple[Type[IntType], Type[IntType]]": "Callable[[IntType, IntType], int]"; expected "Tuple[Type[T?], Type[U?]]": "Callable[[T, U], int]"
```

The errors don't change if I leave `T` and `U` without a `bound` value.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382170/how-can-i-create-my-own-parameterized-type-in-python-like-optionalt)

Answer (score 0):

[Python doesn't have type mappings](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1273).

As with [this similar question on mapping a type to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434302/how-to-annotate-a-dict-of-type-to-function-that-returns-type/76436752), you can implement a `typing.Protocol` with `dict` methods as needed, instead of trying to parameterise a generic dictionary:

```py
from typing import Callable, Protocol, TypeVar

class BaseType: pass
class IntType(BaseType): pass
class StringType(BaseType): pass

def _compare_int_int(before: IntType, after: IntType) -> int:
    return 1

def _compare_int_str(before: IntType, after: StringType) -> int:
    return 2

def _compare_str_int(before: StringType, after: IntType) -> int:
    return 3

def _compare_str_str(before: StringType, after: StringType) -> int:
    return 4

T1 = TypeVar("T1", bound=BaseType)
T2 = TypeVar("T2", bound=BaseType)

class _Comparers(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, item: tuple[type[T1], type[T2]]) -> Callable[[T1, T2], int]: ...
    def __setitem__(self, key: tuple[type[T1], type[T2]], value: Callable[[T1, T2], int]) -> None: ...

    # Add more signatures from `dict` here, if needed


# You'll have to add the entries separately instead of defining a dictionary in one go
_COMPARERS: _Comparers = {}
_COMPARERS[(IntType, IntType)] = _compare_int_int
_COMPARERS[(IntType, StringType)] = _compare_int_str
_COMPARERS[(StringType, StringType)] = _compare_str_str
_COMPARERS[(StringType, IntType)] = _compare_str_int

# mypy: Value of type variable "T1" of "__setitem__" of "_Comparers" cannot be "int" [type-var]
# mypy: Value of type variable "T2" of "__setitem__" of "_Comparers" cannot be "int" [type-var]
# mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[IntType, IntType], int]", target has type "Callable[[int, int], int]") [assignment]
# _COMPARERS[(int, int)] = _compare_int_int

# This is type-safe - no linting errors should occur anywhere in this function
def compare(before: BaseType, after: BaseType) -> int:
    compare_func = _COMPARERS[(type(before), type(after))]
    return compare_func(before, after)


a = IntType()
b = StringType()

print(compare(a, a))
## 1
print(compare(a, b))
## 2
print(compare(b, a))
## 3
print(compare(b, b))
## 4
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest one of the following that might solve the issue:

- Using `TypeVar` with your function is a better way to get the types.
- If you're dealing with built-in types like str and int, why create a class for them? Use the original types

Comment: I've responded to your first suggestion in the post. As for your second...the classes represent SQL data types in the actual application I'm working on, so they don't represent regular Python strings and ints.

Comment: I played around for a bit and it seems like a bug in mypy. The only solution I came up with was to Replace `Callable[[BaseType, BaseType], int]` with `Callable[[Any, Any], int]`

Anyway, operator overloading might yield better results in this example - but likely won't be as clean