# How to annotate a dict of type to function that returns type

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I want to use a dict which maps a type to a callable which returns the same type. E.g.

```
MY_DICT = {
    bytes: lambda x: x,
    int: lambda x: int.from_bytes(x, 'big'),
    str: lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'),
}
```

i.e. each value is a callable which takes a `bytes` value and returns the corresponding type for its key.

I'm wondering how I should annotate this dict for mypy? So far I have come up with:

```
dict[type, typing.Callable[[bytes], typing.Any]]
```

But I'm wondering if there is any way to remove the `typing.Any` and to statically encode that the returned type must match the type key? Thanks for any advice!

I am using python 3.11.

Comment: It's not clear how a type checker could make use of this annotation. Unless you access the dictionary with a literal key, it can't tell what the value type will be, so it can't check it.

Comment: You can't. There isn't a single value type, aside from the union of whatever values are in the `dict` at runtime.

Comment: The type really *is* `Any`, since you can add new elements to the dictionary dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Type mappings](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1273) are not supported in Python (yet?). You can, however, write a `Protocol` which imitates some aspects of [`collections.abc.`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)[`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) to achieve roughly the same effect, if you're willing to forgo writing it as a direct dictionary (dictionary literal):

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

class MyDict(t.Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, item: type[T]) -> t.Callable[[bytes], T]: ...
    def __setitem__(self, key: type[T], value: t.Callable[[bytes], T]) -> None: ...

# Can't write a dictionary literal with all the entries here, but you can initialise, set, and retrieve values in a type-safe manner
MY_DICT: MyDict = {}
MY_DICT[bytes] = lambda x: x
MY_DICT[int] = lambda x: int.from_bytes(x, "big")
MY_DICT[str] = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8")

# Type-checking in effect by mypy
MY_DICT[bytes] = b""  # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "bytes", target has type "Callable[[bytes], bytes]") [assignment]
reveal_type(MY_DICT[list[int]])  # mypy: Revealed type is "def (builtins.bytes) -> builtins.list[builtins.int]"
```

If you need more method API from `dict`, just fill up the method stub signatures in `MyDict`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess what I really want is a Rust-style match on an enum, where each branch takes a concrete enum variant. But since python does not support such a match (or even a switch statement) my understanding is that dicts are the closest built-in alternative. Just means that you always need to use `typing.Any` or an explicit `typing.cast` call to short-circuit the type checking.

Comment: @RyanCollingham Python supports match statements as of Python 3.10 (see https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/). [`@typing.assert_never` can also be used for exhaustiveness checking.](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/unreachable.html#assert-never-and-exhaustiveness-checking). I'm not quite sure what this has got to do with the question though.

Comment: @dROOOze I assume OP is trying to apply the general advice of simulating a switch statement with a `dict` lookup, but for a *typed* lookup, this only works if every case supplies a value of the same type.

Comment: `MY_DICT: MyDict = {}` [fails type-checking](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=7b7b587b9781de677425cffb3fcae278), since dicts aren't actually statically compatible with this protocol. You'd need to make the checker ignore the mismatch with something like `typing.cast`.

Comment: @user2357112 That depends on what mypy infers `{}` to mean without an annotation. For example, [an empty dict initially inferred to be `dict[Any, Any]` definitely isn't incompatible with the protocol](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=0a2403b4175d76ade72aa8739d6655e0). Something must have changed between [mypy==1.6.x](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.6.1&python=3.12&gist=ca785778bb1bfe08ceb253751fa6cafa), which is when I wrote this answer, and now.