# Is it possible to type a dict of type -> handler functions for that type in python?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

eg, imagine a class hierarchy rooted at `Base` (which is abstract) with subclasses `A` and `B`. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)
dispatch: dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], RetType] = {
  A: a_handler,
  B: b_handler
}
```

and have mypy know that `dispatch[type(x)](x)` is well typed (assuming `x: Base`).

This is not possible, because you can't have generics at the top level under mypy; it complains that `T` doesn't mean anything. However, I'd like to avoid a chain of isinstance checks:

```py
if isinstance(x, A):
    return a_handler(x)
elif isintsance(x, B):
    return b_handler
...
```

if it's possible.

Comment: No, type variables do not work this way in python. For cheap dispatch you can wrap this in a function with such signature and use a dict inside it with type-ignore comment (in one place, and have the rest typechecked properly). Single call overhead shouldn't be too bad for your performance.

Comment: I mean, for cheap dispatch I could just use a dict with type-ignores without a function, too. The function adds nothing here

Comment: Function does: it replaces "type ignore every dispatch usage" with "type ignore once in a function body", and then you have proper types outside of it. However, I don't really like this `[type(x)]` dispatch scenario, because it breaks for subclasses. Perhaps you can use a single handler with `functools.singledispatch`?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434302

Answer (score 0):

For the curious (I know there are many), I am probably going to go with something like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=RootClass)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Handler = Callable[[T], ResponseData]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
def mk_dispatch() -> Tuple[Callable[[Type[T]], Callable[[Handler[T]], Handler[T]]],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                           Callable[[T], Optional[Handler[T]]]]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    # _dispatch is typed as `dict[Any, Any]` on purpose: there's no way to                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    # type something like `dict[type[T], Callable[[T], X]]` with an
    # existential or whatever in mypy.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    # that's why `add_dispatch` is two levels, and the outer one takes the                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    # type that the decorated function handles: to prove that the mapping                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    # we're building up is actually correct. This is also why we close over
    # the dict: to prevent manual mucking around with it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    _dispatch: dict = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    def add_dispatch(t: type[T]) -> Callable[[Handler[T]], Handler[T]]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        def _mk_dispatch(f: Handler[T]) -> Handler[T]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            _dispatch[t] = f                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            return f                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        return _mk_dispatch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return (add_dispatch, lambda msg: _dispatch.get(type(msg)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
(add_dispatch, dispatch) = mk_dispatch()
```

The `Protocol` method didn't seem to provide any better typing and was a little more cumbersome. "Couldn't you just use `functools.singledispatch`?" you perhaps ask. Yes, but I like the explicit way of handling the fallback case in which the key isn't found this offers a little better.