# How to define a dict that maps types with callables that recieve arguments of that type?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

In Python, I have trouble defining a type. I would like something like this:

```py
def foo(x: int) -> int:
    return x
    
def bar(x: str) -> str:
    return x

# [...] MyDictType would be defined here...
        
my_dict: MyDictType = {
    int: foo,       # Good
    str: bar,       # Good
    float: bar      # WRONG! Type warning!
}
```

MyDictType should indicate that it is a dict that maps a type with a callable that receives a variable of that type. I was wondering about how to do it using generics... but I am not sure. I have tried this:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

MyDictType = dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], T]]
```

However, the editor does not show the error I was expecting in the dict's third entry...

How should I define MyDictType?

Comment: What are you gonna do when you encounter a function with 0 or >1 parameters? Sounds like you'll want to use tuples for keys

Comment: No. I just want to map types with one function that receives and returns values of that types. If I tried to add a function with 0 or >1 parameters, then it should show that type checking error.

Comment: `MyDictType` is a generic type. `T` is bound once for a whole instantiation of the generic type, not separately per element. `my_dict: MyDictType` is effectively `my_dict: MyDictType[Any]` as far as static type checkers are concerned, which is why `float: bar` type-checks.

Comment: Oh, thank you. How should I define it then?

Comment: You could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434302/how-to-annotate-a-dict-of-type-to-function-that-returns-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this. No annotation can express a relation between the types of individual dict keys and their corresponding values.

The closest you can get is defining a wrapper:

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class TypeMapperThing:
    _mapping: dict[type, Callable[[Any], Any]]
    def __init__(self):
        self._mapping = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> Callable[[T], T]:
        return self._mapping[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key: type[T], value: Callable[[T], T]) -> None:
        self._mapping[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key: type[T]) -> None:
        del self[key]
```

Here, the wrapper hides the use of `Any` and provides a type-safe external API. (I could have omitted the type arguments on `Callable` and just written `_mapping: dict[type, Callable]`, but that would use `Callable[..., Any]` instead of `Callable[[Any], Any]`. It barely matters, though.)

Note that there is no good way to make `__init__` take a dict, or to write an `update` method that takes a dict. Trying to do so runs into the original problem of trying to write a type for that dict.

I have also refrained from using `collections.abc.Mapping` or `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, as those ABCs define an interface that runs into similar problems to `dict`.