python typing TypeVar: understanding unbound error
I do not understand error like

Type variable "T" is unbound

Here a concrete example:
from typing import Dict, Type, Callable, TypeVar

class Sup: ...
class A(Sup): ...
class B(Sup): ...

def get_A(a: A) -> int:
    return 1

def get_B(b: B) -> int:
    return 2

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Sup)

f: Dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], int]] = {A: get_A, B: get_B}

mypy returns:
error: Type variable "foo.T" is unbound  [valid-type]
note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "type[A]": "Callable[[A], int]"; expected "type[T?]": "Callable[[T], int]"  [dict-item]
error: Dict entry 1 has incompatible type "type[B]": "Callable[[B], int]"; expected "type[T?]": "Callable[[T], int]"  [dict-item]

My understanding (which may be incorrect), is that mypy complains because it can not guarantee that later on, no tuple (key, value) not following the constrain on T  will be added. For example:
# not a subclass of Sup !
class D: ...

def get_D(d: D)->int:
  return 2

f[D] = get_D  # D is not a subclass of Sup, so violation of the type of f

Question:

is my understanding of the error correct ? If not, could an explanation be provided ?

if my understanding is correct, why would the error occur here:


f: Dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], int]] = {A: get_A, B: get_B}

and not here ?
# This is the line not respecting the type of f !
f[D] = get_D 


Only generic classes and functions build typevars. dict is neither of them - you cannot express "dict mapping T to Something[T]" in python's type system.

This question is similar to: How to add type hints for a dictionary that maps a class to an instance of that class?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336818/python-type-hinting-a-dictionary-mapping-types-to-functions

@STerliakov The question is similar, but not identical. The question you link to asks for a solution, and indeed a solution is provided as answer. My question asks for an explanation of why "unbound" error occurs, with a concrete example to avoid the explanation to be too abstract.

TypeVar binding
First of all, what does "Type variable "T" is unbound" mean? Let's clarify things, since it has nothing to do with its bound argument.
When you use a type variable, you assign it some scope. This is not the runtime scope (global) where you define a T = TypeVar('T'). In a generic class, the variable is bound by Generic[T] (or Protocol[T], or some other class that is already generic) base class: when you use this form, you can use this type variable within the class body, so it's class-scoped. In a generic function, the variable is bound merely by inclusion into signature and is function-scoped. Here's another snippet that produces the same error (playground):
from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")

def fn() -> int:
    x: _T = 2
    return 1

This error does not relate to such complicated matters as you consider: you are simply not allowed to use a type variable that is not assigned a scope (bound).
Only generic functions and classes bind type vars for their bodies, and also a type alias can use free type vars in its right-hand side (strictly speaking, that isn't "use in annotation" since that part is a plain runtime assignment).
This should be more clear with PEP695 generic syntax (I'm not a big fan of it, but can't argue it makes scoping more clear): you can declare a type var for function, for class and for a type alias. You cannot declare a type var for anything else.
def fn[T](x: T) -> T:
    y: T = x
    # You can use T here

class Foo[T]:
    foo: T  # You can use T here

    def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
        y: T = x  # And here (class-scoped, but also present in the func)
    
    def foo(self) -> None:
        y: T = self.foo  # But also here - you already "allocated" T for the class

type Bar[T] = dict[T, T]

# All three T's above are different
# And you can't use T here
x: T  # Typechecker error!

Note how the type variable is created for some scope (function/class/type alias). You couldn't rewrite your example using 3.12 syntax - and no, it isn't because new syntax isn't powerful enough. That just isn't supported by python's type system.

if my understanding is correct, why would the error occur here:

f: Dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], int]] = {A: get_A, B: get_B}

Because it's the place where you use a type variable not bound to current scope.
Why are all other uses rejected?
Because of scoping! Consider your idea (simplified - callable is irrelevant, right?):
T = TypeVar("T")

x: dict[T, T]

If I understand correctly, you want it to be interpreted like this (forgetting about all other methods, see typeshed for a wall of them):
_K = TypeVar("_K")
_V = TypeVar("_V")

class dict(Generic[_K, _V]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: _K, /) -> _V: ...
    def __delitem__(self, key: _K, /) -> None: ...


# dict[T, T] is equivalent to substituting T for both _K and _V
class YourDict(Generic[T]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: T, /) -> T: ...
    def __delitem__(self, key: T, /) -> None: ...

So YourDict is something equivalent to dict[T, T] using your syntax.
Let's unwrap this: T in YourDict is class scoped. It is the same for all places where it's mentioned inside the class body. At this point, type checkers can forget about the fact that __getitem__ could also be a generic function outside of class context, because it cannot "own" that T. Compare with __delitem__ where T would make no sense at all shall we "forget" about class binding. So, there could be YourDict[int] or YourDict[str] - types that have __getitem__ accepting and returning int or str, resp., same as dict[int, int].
There is no way to express "substitute generic's typevar with another typevar, but only method-scoped" - mostly because this use case is pretty niche and semantics would be terribly difficult to define (what should happen to methods with only one typevar reference - __delitem__ above?).
You might be inspired by this example similar to one from PEP484 (references below):
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
        self._x = x

    def method(self, x: T, y: S) -> S: ...

x = Foo(1)  # Foo[int]
y = x.method(0, "abc")  # inferred type of y is str

Recommended reading

Relevant PEP484 section
Mypy docs about generics


Thanks for the didactic answer. I remain confused. I define T: T = TypeVar("T", bound=Sup). Isn't T defined in the current scope ? For example, I could use T as the type of a function argument. Yet, not in a Dict ?

T is defined for runtime, that's an implication of not having dedicated syntax for typevars, but still cannot be used. You could use it for a function argument, parent class subscript in a class definition, or for a generic type alias, but not for anything else - this list is exhaustive.

Apologies if I am a bit slow. "but not for anything else". Why not ? Is there some fundamental reason why this could not be used for Dict ? (the answer focuses on scope, but I do not see how this relevant here, as the TypeVar is defined in the current scope)
